# Uniform convergence of $f^2_n$ when $f_n$ converges uniformly

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions that converge uniformly to $f$ on the interval $I$.

Prove or disprove: $f^2_n \to f^2$ uniformly on I.

I was almost certain this claim is false but was unable to construct any example. After several hours I started to try and prove it.

What i have so far is that if we can prove that $\sup_{x \in I}|f_n(f_n-f)| \ \to 0$ we're done. But after playing for another couple of hours with different functions i'm starting to believe it could be wrong.

I'm really at a loss here and any intuition i had about sequences seems to have been lost with this problem.

Comment: Perhaps part of the reason why this is so counterintuitive is that you haven't required the $f_n$ to be continuous. The main idea behind uniform convergence is to create a system of convergence such that the limit of continuous functions is continuous... a lot of weird things can happen if we don't have continuity

Answer (score 7):

Let $f_n(x) = x+{1 \over n} $, $f(x) = x$. Then $f_n \to f$ uniformly, but
$f_n(n)^2-f(n)^2 = { 2 n^2 +1  \over n^2}$, hence the square does not converge uniformly.

By considering $f_n \circ \tan$, $f \circ \tan$ (and appropriate adjustments for the argument above), we can apply similar considerations to the open interval $(0,{\pi \over 2})$.

Comment: Dang it, I was going to post this.

Comment: Well, I am being liberal with 'interval' here.

Comment: Shoot, I just finished writing almost this exact example.... Of course, one could easily adapt this example to the case of a closed interval, unless there's a continuity assumption.

Comment: Is that a typo? I thought it should be $\frac{2xn+1}{n^{2}}$

Comment: @Gina: No, take $x=n$.

Comment: @copper.hat: oh I see, sorry did not notice that. It cannot done for closed bounded interval and continuous function though, since $f$ being unbounded is necessary for the counterexample.

Answer (score 5):

If $f_n+f $ is bounded, then $f_n^2-f^2=(f_n-f)(f_n+f) \rightarrow 0$ .

Comment: Do you know what uniform convergence means?

Comment: Yes, I do, do you?

Comment: Certainly I do. Another question: Do you think that $f^2_n \to f^2$ uniformly, or not?

Comment: Let $f_n+f$ be bounded by M. Then choose an n so that $|f_n(x)-f|< e/2M $ for all x ( by uniform continuity of f_n). Then $|f_n^2-f^2| \leq (|e/2M|)M$

Comment: @TonyK:But , while I am not clear on the domain, if it is the reals, $f_n+f=2x+1/n$ is not bounded, which is the case I am working with here. Do you see a specific flaw with my argument?

Comment: @TonyK this answer is a correct and useful statement.  If you have an objection, you should be clearer about it.

Comment: @TonyK: I am giving a partial answer, and I think I made an explicit statement of this. And, please, you may not have meant it, but the tone of the question seemed condescending; please consider this.

Comment: This answer is indeed correct if $f_n$ is continuous, and $I$ is closed and bounded...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: There is no guarantee that $f_n + f$ is bounded.

Comment: @TonyK: Please see my argument a few posts above and tell me if you see something wrong with it , _under the assumptions I make explicitly_.

Comment: @TonyK i) the assumption of boundedness is useful under some pieces of information that are likely to be added to this question and ii) the implication is that $f_n^2 - f \to 0$ **uniformly** (which should probably be stated explicitly for clarity), implying that $f_n^2 \to f$ uniformly, which was to be proven.